# Asynchronous callbacks in a loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, ms-office, office-js

I have a variable `oldBindings` which record all the existing bindings of an Excel table. I have built `BindingDataChanged` listeners based on `oldBindings`. So when `newBindings` come up, I need to remove all the old listeners linked to `oldBindings` and add new listeners based on `newBindings`. At the moment, I have written the following code:

```
var oldBindings = ["myBind1", "myBind2"]; // can be updated by other functions

function updateEventHandlers(newBindings) {
    removeEventHandlers(oldBindings, function () {
        addEventHandlers(newBindings)
    })
}

function removeEventHandlers(oldBindings, cb) {
    for (var i = 0; i < oldBindings.length; i++) {
        Office.select("binding#"+oldBindings[i]).removeHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.BindingDataChanged, function (asyncResult) {
            Office.context.document.bindings.releaseByIdAsync(oldBindings[i], function () {});
        });
    }
    cb()
}
```

As `removeHandlerAsync` and `releaseByIdAsync` are built with `callback` rather than `promise`, I need to organise the whole code with `callback`. There are 2 things I am not sure:

1) in `removeEventHandlers`, will `cb()` ALWAYS be executed after the removal of all the listeners? How could I ensure that?

2) Do I have to make `addEventHandlers` as a `callback` of `removeEventHandlers` to ensure their execution order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) in `removeEventHandlers`, will cb() ALWAYS be executed after the removal of all the listeners?

No. It'll be called after the *initiation* of the removal. But if the removal is async, it may be called before the removal is complete.

> 2) Do I have to make `addEventHandlers` as a callback of `removeEventHandlers` to ensure their execution order?

Yes, but not the way you have. The way you have is just like doing

```
removeEventHandlers();
addEventHandlers();
```

because you call `cb` at the end of `removeEventHandlers` without waiting for anything to finish.

> As `removeHandlerAsync` and `releaseByIdAsync` are built with `callback` rather than `promise`, I need to organise the whole code with `callback`.

Or you could give yourself Promise versions of them. More on that in a moment.

Using the non-Promise callback approach, to ensure you call `cb` from `removeEventHandlers` when all the work is done, remember how many callbacks you're expecting and wait until you get that many before calling `cb`:

```
var oldBindings = ["myBind1", "myBind2"]; // can be updated by other functions

function updateEventHandlers(newBindings) {
    removeEventHandlers(oldBindings, function() {
        addEventHandlers(newBindings);
    });
}

function removeEventHandlers(oldBindings, cb) {
    var waitingFor = oldBindings.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < oldBindings.length; i++) {
        Office.select("binding#"+oldBindings[i]).removeHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.BindingDataChanged, function (asyncResult) {
            Office.context.document.bindings.releaseByIdAsync(oldBindings[i], function () {
                if (--waitingFor == 0) {
                    cb();
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

But any time you have a callback system, you can Promise-ify it:

```
function removeHandlerPromise(obj, eventType) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        obj.removeHandlerAsync(eventType, function(asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                reject(asyncResult.error);
            } else {
                resolve(asyncResult.value);
            }
        });
    });
}

function releaseByIdPromise(obj, value) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        obj.releaseByIdAsync(value, function(asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                reject(asyncResult.error);
            } else {
                resolve(asyncResult.value);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Then that lets you do this:

```
var oldBindings = ["myBind1", "myBind2"]; // can be updated by other functions

function updateEventHandlers(newBindings) {
    removeEventHandlers(oldBindings).then(function() {
        addEventHandlers(newBindings);
    });
}

function removeEventHandlers(oldBindings) {
    return Promise.all(oldBindings.map(function(binding) {
        return removeHandlerPromise(Office.select("binding#"+binding), Office.EventType.BindingDataChanged).then(function() {
            return releaseByIdPromise(Office.context.document.bindings, binding);
        });
    });
}
```

Or you can give yourself a generic Promise-ifier for any async op that returns an `AsyncResult`:

```
function promisify(obj, method) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        args.push(function(asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                reject(asyncResult.error);
            } else {
                resolve(asyncResult.value);
            }
        });
        obj[method].apply(obj, args);
    });
}
```

Then that lets you do this:

```
var oldBindings = ["myBind1", "myBind2"]; // can be updated by other functions

function updateEventHandlers(newBindings) {
    removeEventHandlers(oldBindings).then(function() {
        addEventHandlers(newBindings);
    });
}

function removeEventHandlers(oldBindings) {
    return Promise.all(oldBindings.map(function(binding) {
        return promisify(Office.select("binding#"+binding), "removeHandlerAsync", Office.EventType.BindingDataChanged).then(function() {
            return promisify(Office.context.document.bindings, "releaseByIdAsync", binding);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Agreed regarding wrapping the callback into a promise if it makes your code logic easier.